# Passing environment variable

Tags: python, networkx

How can I pass the environment  variable (env) in the switch class using the mapping in the `Relabel_node` Function?

Actually I tried:

```
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping=switch(env) ,copy=True
```

But it didn't work, giving me error.
It's essential for passing the env variable for the simulation to begin.

```
**class switch(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.env = env
        self.store = simpy.Store(env)
        self.rate = 100
        self.out = None
        self.packets_rec = 0
        self.packets_drop = 0
        self.qlimit = None
        self.byte_size = 0  # Current size of the queue in bytes
        self.debug = False
        self.interfaces = []
        self.numinterfaces = 16
        self.busy = 0
        for i in range(self.numinterfaces):
            self.interfaces.append(SwitchPort(env, self.rate))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.id

def edges_():
    """ Return the lanl internet view graph from lanl.edges
    """

    try:
        fh = open('edges.list', 'r')
    except IOError:
        print("File not found")
        raise

    G = nx.Graph()

    for line in fh.readlines():
        (node1, node2) = line.split()
        G.add_edge(str(node1), str(node2))

    # get largest component and assign ping times to G0time dictionary

    return G

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import networkx as nx

    env = simpy.Environment()
    G = edges_()
    H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping=switch ,copy=True)
    print("The graph has %d nodes with %d edges" \
          % (nx.number_of_nodes(H), nx.number_of_edges(H)))**
```

Comment: Read the [documentation for `relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html). You're passing in a `switch` object (or at the end of your example, the `switch` class itself), but you need to pass a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Switch Class Code, argument being passed to switch object should be `id` and not `env` so modify Switch class to accept two variables id and env like this:

```
class switch(object):
    def __init__(self, id, env):
        self.id = id
        self.env = env
```

Then call for Switch object creation will be:

```
 H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping=switch(id, env) ,copy=True)
```

Comment: Tried It
AttributeError: switch instance has no __call__ method